# Extracting data from Web or PDF to Excel (not in standard columns)

Tags: excel, pdf, web-scraping

I want to analyze salaries at the University of Illinois. Being a public institution they release all salary data but it's in a web and pdf format. One cannot sort by highest salary, department or do any other type of analysis on this. I'm trying to get this data in a table format for analysis.

On this link we have Salaries at the University of Illinois:
http://www.trustees.uillinois.edu/trustees/resources/17-18-Graybook/TOC.html

University of Illinois is composed of 3 campuses:
1.    Urbana
2.    Chicago
3.    Springfield

[image: You can see campus name at the top of each section - there are 3 sections.]

Each campus is then broken out into Colleges:

[image: Each campus is then broken out into Colleges:]

In the above screenshot we are seeing Chicago Campus with colleges GF and FL.

Then when you click into the college, you can see the following:

[image]

At the top below Employee Name, you can see the College Name then under that is the Department then finally under that we have the names of employees and their salaries.

I want this data put into Excel Format

There is one more complication:
Some employees have two jobs as shown below:[image]

So as an example, Corte, Anthony will show up on the list twice since he has two jobs then under both those jobs it will say "Employee Total for All Jobs". To start with, I want to just ignore the line "Employee Total for All Jobs". Then later on I will create a total myself either by putting the second job in a new column or some other solution.

Here's how I want it to look in Excel:
[image]

A PDF of the data is also provided here:
http://www.trustees.uillinois.edu/trustees/resources/GrayBook2017.pdf

What I've tried:
Convert PDF document to Excel. The problem with this is that I then have to manually reorganize the College, department headings into separate columns. In addition the "Employee total for all jobs" throws things off as it puts the name into two columns.

Copying from website into Excel. Again the same issue of the certain fields copying into multiple rows which then throws things off and have to be fixed manually.

I'm looking for ideas on how to put this data into a table format the easiest and fastest way (there are over 400 pages of data in the pdf). Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: You can capture data from the web page into your excel using VBA. Have a look at using **Microsoft Internet Controls** with VBA

Answer (score 0):

Pdf is not a WYSIWYG format. Think of it more as a container of instructions for rendering than a plain text format.

That means the actual content for rendering a table may:

- may be scattered over the entire stream (representing a page)
- does not need to appear in logical reading order
- words do not need to appear in the content stream as such (compression)

You can (sort of) make this work.
use iText to attach an IEventListener to the PDF. This listener will get notified every time a PDF instruction is processed.
There are 3 kinds:

- PathRenderInfo (for drawing lines)
- ImageRenderInfo (for rendering images)
- TextRenderInfo (for rendering text)

If you already know all your tables will always have most of their lines drawn (rather than having an implicit table by text layout), you can implement some kind of algorithm that gather PathRenderInfo objects and aggregates them if the lines cross at straight angles. Then inspect those clusters to find tables.
Within those clusters, you can then attempt to find text by checking out the TextRenderInfo objects that lay within the boundaries of the table, and that have roughly the same alignment (indicating rows or columns).

This is certainly not easy, and in fact there are various thesis papers on how to do this, each with different approaches, and each with varying measures of success.

The alternative is that you use pdf2Data. An iText7 add-on that is capable of mapping templates to documents matching the template.

http://pdf2data.online/